# Tries - Contacts - Hackerrank

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, prefix

I am currently trying to solve this challenge on hackerrank [Tries - Contacts](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-contacts/problem)

And my algorithm fails for only one test case. Test case #1. Can any one share any insight into what I need to change in order to pass this test case. I am using a TrieNode class that contains a hashmap of its children nodes. I also store the size of each node to deonte how many words it contains.

Test case #1 is as follows:

```
add s 
add ss
add sss
add ssss
add sssss
find s
find ss
find sss
find ssss
find sssss
find ssssss
```

The code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    TrieNode root;

    class TrieNode{
        Map<Character, TrieNode> children = new HashMap<Character, TrieNode>();
        int size=0;
    }

    public Solution(){
        root = new TrieNode();
    }

    public void addWord(String word){
        TrieNode current = root;
        for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++){
            char c = word.charAt(i);
            if(!current.children.containsKey(c)){
                //create a new node
                TrieNode temp = new TrieNode();
                //add the word to the current node's children
                current.children.put(c, temp);
                current.size++;
                current = temp;
            }
            else{
                current.size++;
                current = current.children.get(c);
            }
        }
    }

    public void prefixSearch(String letters){

        TrieNode current = root;
        boolean sequenceExists = true;

        for(int i=0; i<letters.length();i++){
            char c = letters.charAt(i);
            if(current.children.containsKey(c)){
                if(i == letters.length()-1){
                    System.out.println(current.size);
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    current = current.children.get(c);
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(0);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        Solution sol = new Solution();
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < n; a0++){
            String op = in.next();
            String contact = in.next();

            if(op.equals("add")){
                if(contact.length() >=1 && contact.length() <=21)
                sol.addWord(contact);
            }
            else if(op.equals("find")){
                if(contact.length() >=1 && contact.length() <=21)
                sol.prefixSearch(contact);
            }
            else{
                //do nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's Test Case #1?

Comment: I will add it to he question

Comment: For a second there I thought you were possessed by a python.

Comment: What happens when you try the input you mentioned, and what should've happened instead?

Comment: yes lol...the formatting is pretty bad here

Comment: Yeah, comments don't retain formatting.

Comment: I have added the test case to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add words to your Trie you increment count for all nodes, except the last one. This is quite common and hard to notice kind of error called off-by-one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

add this line once again at the end of addWord method (after the loop):

```
current.size++;
```

Your code passed test case 0 because this particular bug in your code doesn't show up when you look up a prefix like *hac-kerrank*, but does show up when you look up for complete word including the **last** character like *hackerran**k***, or *ssss**s***

Comment: thanks Milo Bem. I would have never caught that. I still don't understand it. Let me try to re-read what you have written and try and digest it. That however was the issue. Great catch btw.

Comment: What's a strategy to look for these?

Comment: Have a read at the wikipedia article I linked, some examples are actually quite similar to your case. Like I wrote, this kind of error is often hard to notice because it only shows up in particular situations, like when you hit exactly the border case. That's why proper testing is important in commercial programming.

Comment: Awesome. thanks a lot. I've done all I can to give you more points like mark the answer right and up vote. Let me know if I missed anyhing. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution, except test case 0, 1 & 5 all others are timing out. Here is my implementation in java 8. Where should I improve my code to pass all the test cases

```
public class Contacts {
    static Map<String, String> contactMap = new HashMap<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();

        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < n; a0++){
            String op = in.next();
            String contact = in.next();
            if(op.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
                addOrFind(contact, op);
            } else {
                addOrFind(contact, op);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void addOrFind(String name, String type) {
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
            contactMap.put(name, name);
        } else {
            long count = contactMap.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(p->p.getKey().contains(name)).count();
            System.out.println(count);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: did you figure it out yet?

Comment: @Spindoctor I have read some solutions using Trie, but not using my current implementation

Answer (score 0):

If you will checkout:[enter link description here](https://github.com/RodneyShag/HackerRank_solutions/blob/master/Data%20Structures/Trie/Contacts/Solution.java)

And also use their test case of:
4
add hack
add hackerrank
find hac
find hak

It will compile.

// from his website at https://github.com/RodneyShag/HackerRank_solutions/blob/master/Data%20Structures/Trie/Contacts/Solution.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        Trie trie = new Trie();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String operation = scan.next();
            String contact   = scan.next();
            if (operation.equals("add")) {
                trie.add(contact);
            } else if (operation.equals("find")) {
                System.out.println(trie.find(contact));
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
/* Based loosely on tutorial video in this problem */
class TrieNode {
    private HashMap<Character, TrieNode> children = new HashMap<>();
    public int size = 0; // this was the main trick to decrease runtime to pass tests.
    public void putChildIfAbsent(char ch) {
        children.putIfAbsent(ch, new TrieNode());
    }
    public TrieNode getChild(char ch) {
        return children.get(ch);
    }
}
class Trie {
    TrieNode root = new TrieNode();
    Trie(){} // default constructor

    Trie(String[] words) {
        for (String word : words) {
            add(word);
        }
    }

    public void add(String str) {
        TrieNode curr = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            Character ch = str.charAt(i);
            curr.putChildIfAbsent(ch);
            curr = curr.getChild(ch);
            curr.size++;
        }
    }

    public int find(String prefix) {
        TrieNode curr = root;

        /* Traverse down tree to end of our prefix */
        for (int i = 0; i < prefix.length(); i++) {
            Character ch = prefix.charAt(i);
            curr = curr.getChild(ch);
            if (curr == null) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return curr.size;
    }
}
```